# Plotting a lineplot from a single line dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe with just a row [A screenshot of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pducT.png)

How do I plot it as line plot with the x axis being the columns and the y axis being the values?